# Norm-preserving map is linear

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

How can one show that a norm-preserving map $T: X \rightarrow X'$ where $X,X'$ are vector spaces and $T(0) = 0$ is linear? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by norm-preserving? Note that if $T$ is not linear, then $|Tx| = |x|$ does *not* mean that $|Tx - Ty| = |x - y|$, which is what is usually meant (and as noted below, your claim is false if you only require $|Tx| = |x|$ and true in many cases if you actually meant distance-preserving).

Comment: Related threads: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121046, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81086, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/16965

Answer (score 5):

The claim is false. For example, take $X=X'=\mathbb{R}$, and $T(x)=|x|$ for all $x$.

Comment: I think, for nonlinear maps, "norm preserving" has to mean $\|T(x)-T(y)\| = \|x-y\|$.

Comment: @GEdgar, the OP assumes also $T(0)=0$ and so $\|T(x)-T(y)\| = \|x-y\|$ implies $\|T(x)\| = \|x\|$.

Comment: But not conversely.

Answer (score 3):

This claim is true if your map $T$ is surjective and is an isometry. In this case simply apply [Mazur-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem).

If we do not require that map is surjective, but only norm-preserving, then we can construct a counterexample
$$
T:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}:z\mapsto z e^{i |z|}
$$
where $\mathbb{C}$ is considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hold on, the link you gave refers to isometries, but there are functions that are norm-preserving but not isometries (e.g. the norm function itself). Are you sure the theorem applies?

Comment: @benmachine So what is yours definition of norm-preserving?

Comment: $|f(x)| = |x|$ for all $x$. Since $f(x)-f(y)$ need not be $f(x-y)$, this need not mean that $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x - y|$.

Comment: Oh, in this case you are right. Then even for surjective maps we can construct counterexamples.

Comment: Yeah, on second thoughts, norm-preserving as I phrased it is a pretty silly condition. I can't imagine the OP doesn't mean isometry.

Comment: Also, your wikipedia link cites [this PDF](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/mazurulam.pdf) as a source which in passing mentions that *any* isometry to a strictly convex ("that is, no sphere contains a line segment") space is also affine, and any inner-product space and $\ell_p$ for $1<p<\infty$ is strictly convex.

Comment: The Mazur-Ulam theorem is a result that only holds for *real* vector spaces. On complex vector spaces you have many counterexamples, perhaps worth mentioning: $z \mapsto \bar{z}$.